# Is it possible to use ant's antlr task to do code generation with stringtemplate?

Tags: ant, antlr, stringtemplate

Is it possible to use ant's antlr task to do code generation with the stringtemplate library?
If not, is it better to just execute a java class from command line to code gen w/ stringtemplate?

I've found this link which is close to what I want, but I am having a hard time setting this up properly.  That library is not able to see antlr for some reason. [link text](http://www.howardism.org/thoughts/001217.html)

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the complexity of the code that you want to generate. In case of our company, we extended org.apache.tools.ant.Task with the generation logic for java code. After that, both ant task and template files were packaged in a jar file.